# Trying to understand a CSS chain

Tags: forms, css

can anybody explain the following code snippet (used in CSS):

```
[type="checkbox"]:checked
```

I've tried to find this on various sites, I understand the pseudo class on the end but the square brackets have really got me stumped.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: [**Attribute Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[type="checkbox"]` is an [**attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

This specific selector will match any element that has the attribute `type` and that attribute's value is `checkbox`. Most would identify this as a selector for and `input` but is not specific enough to be limited to that element type. Other elements that accept the `type` attribute are `<button>` `<command>`, `<embed>`, `<object>`, `<script>`, `<source>`, `<style>` and `<menu>`.

You'll often see `input` pre-pended to a selector like the one above, i.e. `input[type="checkbox"]`, when targeting specific types of `input`.

Comment: So basically put I'm selecting any type attribute with a value of checkbox?

If so, couldn't I achieve the same thing quite easily with a class?

Is the only advantage I don't have to increase my HTML (through more classes)?

Comment: Attribute selectors have the **same level of specificity** as a class, and yes, you could achieve the same thing using a class. The advantage with attribute selectors is that you potentially don't have to add any classes or IDs to the markup. This could also be handy if you were in a situation where you couldn't modify the markup but had access to the stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

this `[type="checkbox"]` is an [**attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> **[attr=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is exactly "value".

[`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) is:

> a pseudo class selector represents any radio (`<input type="radio">`),
>   checkbox (`<input type="checkbox">`) or option (`<option>` in a `<select>`)
>   element that is checked or toggled to an on state. The user can change
>   this state by clicking on the element, or selecting a different value,
>   in which case the `:checked` pseudo-class no longer applies to this
>   element, but will to the relevant one.

Which means you have a checkbox element checked

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets target an attribute such as type for an input elemet.
In your case you're selecting a checked checkbox.